# SQL copy values of column a of table A into column b of table B

Tags: sql, copy

I need to copy the values of column a of table A into column b of Table B.

Is this statement correct?

```
UPDATE
    TableA,
    TableB
SET
    TableB.b = TableA.a
WHERE
TableA.Id = TableB.Id
```

Comment: It's correct, if you have corresponding ids in those tables. Tell us more about your structure!

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: INSERT INTO DESTINATION_TABLE SELECT * FROM SOURCE TABLE?

Comment: UPDATE TABLE B SET TABLE B COLUMN = TABLE A COLUMN FROM TABLE A WHERE YOUR CONDITION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column of the destination is empty and you do not need to match something just use this

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTb ([ColumnName])
SELECT [ColumnNameToTransfer] FROM [SourceTable]
```

if not just with a join

```
update A
SET A.Columnname = B.ColumnNameToTransfer
from DestinationTb A
INNER JOIN 
SourceTable B
ON 
--HERE ADD YOUR MATCHING FOR EXAMPLE
A.ID = B.ID;
```

or with a subquery

```
UPDATE DestinationTb
    SET ColumnName = (
        SELECT ColumnNameToTransfer
        FROM SourceTable
   --HERE ADD YOUR MATCHING FOR EXAMPLE
        WHERE SourceTable.id = DestinationTb.id
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `FROM` and `JOIN` behind `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE A
SET A.a= B.b
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
```